# Is it possible to rotate glare streaks in compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, glare

Is it possible to rotate glare streaks in compositor?

I need these stars rotating. May be i will use blinking changing iterations, but rotation is better for my purpose.

[image: Compositing Glare]

Comment: if you choose Streaks instead of Simle Star you'll have an angle value, I don't know why there's no angle for Simple Star

Comment: i even don't see that much difference between that two... ;) ....now waiting for the comments who will kill me for that.... :D

Comment: Hmm... I tried. It doesn't look good and it has a limit in 180° in only one way rotation.

Comment: I thought maybe there is something like mapping in object shading

Comment: @Chris, I want to downvote you soooo much, too bad I can't   :(((

Comment: @RusDark It looks like there's no solution, Simple Star seems to be a simpler version of Streaks, the Compositor is great but it has some limits

Comment: @RusDark: what's the problem with 180 degree limit? it's looking anyway the same on 0, 90 and 180 degrees? so if you want to animate it, just animate 0 to 90, and then cycle that. if you want other way around, animate 90 to 0 degrees. I don't get your problem?

Comment: @moonboots: i can write a shitty answer, and you can downvote that. I do everything to make YOU happy! :D

Comment: @Chris, oh yes please, do it  ^^

Comment: @Chris, 180° is not enough for example to cook a cake

Comment: @moonboots: answer written - waiting for downvotes.... :D

Comment: @Chris my god your answer is so bad I will need several account to downvote as much as it deserves  :/

Answer (score 3):

Here is my shitty answer - just for my special girlfriend - MOONBOOTS:

You can use "streaks" instead of "simple stars" for that.

You can keyframe angle offset from 0-90, then cycle that.

[image]

Result looks like this:

[image]

and of course with my cool star shader setup:

[image]

[image]

Special hint:

use handle type vector so you won't see that damn lagging of the animation as you can see in my gif:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the effort

Comment: love you too!!!!

Comment: btw i don't want to disappoint you but i'm not a girl

Comment: mmh....ok....mmmh...but....MY girl? :D